# How do I direct inline HTML to a variable?

Tags: php, string, io-redirection

This PHP code outputs HTML to the user.

```
    <div class="whole">
        <input type="hidden" class="hid" name="hid" value="<?php echo $datum['id']; ?>">
        <div class="col1">  <div class="d1" id="naam<?php echo $datum['id']; ?>"><?php echo $datum['name']; ?></div>        
        </div>
        <div class="col2">  <div class="d2" id="email<?php echo $datum['id']; ?>"><?php echo $datum['email']; ?></div>

        </div>
        <div class="col3">  <div class="d3" id="state<?php echo $datum['id']; ?>"><?php echo $datum['state']; ?></div>

        </div>
        <div class="col4">  <div class="d4" id="gender<?php echo $datum['id']; ?>"><?php echo $datum['gender']; ?></div>

        </div>
        <div class="col5">  <div class="d5" id="lang<?php echo $datum['id']; ?>"><?php echo $datum['lang']; ?></div>

        </div>
        <div class="col6">
            <?php
                echo "<a href='images/".$datum['image']."' data-lightbox='picbox' data-title='".$datum['image']."'> <img src='images/".$datum['image']."'></a>";
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Instead of sending this output to the user, I want it in the variable `$output`. How can I do this?

Comment: how is the HTML generated?

Comment: Had tried something? You should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jquery](https://jquery.com/) to get HTML code inside your div:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    data = $(".whole").html();
    console.log(data);
});
```

Where data is:

```
<input type="hidden" class="hid" name="hid" value="<?php echo $datum['id']; ?>">
<div class="col1">  <div class="d1" id="naam<?php echo $datum['id']; ?>"><!--?php echo $datum['name']; ?--></div>
</div>
<div class="col2">  <div class="d2" id="email<?php echo $datum['id']; ?>"><!--?php echo $datum['email']; ?--></div>

</div>
<div class="col3">  <div class="d3" id="state<?php echo $datum['id']; ?>"><!--?php echo $datum['state']; ?--></div>

</div>
<div class="col4">  <div class="d4" id="gender<?php echo $datum['id']; ?>"><!--?php echo $datum['gender']; ?--></div>

</div>
<div class="col5">  <div class="d5" id="lang<?php echo $datum['id']; ?>"><!--?php echo $datum['lang']; ?--></div>

</div>
<div class="col6">
    <!--?php
        echo "<a href='images/".$datum['image']."' data-lightbox='picbox' data-title='".$datum['image']."'--> <img src="images/&quot;.$datum[" image']."'="">";
    ?&gt;
```

After that you can send `data` to PHP via [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
    your html goes here
<?php
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: It'd help if you explained why this code works. Also, why didn't you just use a heredoc?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455517/php-vs-ob-start Heredoc is just ugly I suppose(for me)

Comment: So why don't you use `ob_get_clean`? https://stackoverflow.com/q/17792817/5223757

Comment: There are so many ways to do the same thing in php, it really doesn't matter how you do stuff as long as they work and are understandable...

Answer (score 0):

Use [heredoc syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), like so:

```
$output = <<<ANY_IDENTIFIER_THAT_DOES_NOT_APPEAR_IN_THE_TEXT_HERE
<div class="whole">
    <input type="hidden" class="hid" name="hid" value="{$datum['id']}">
    <div class="col1">  <div class="d1" id="naam{$datum['id']}">{$datum['name']}</div>        
    </div>
    <div class="col2">  <div class="d2" id="email{$datum['id']}">{$datum['email']}</div>

    </div>
    <div class="col3">  <div class="d3" id="state{$datum['id']}">{$datum['state']}</div>

    </div>
    <div class="col4">  <div class="d4" id="gender{$datum['id']}">{$datum['gender']}</div>

    </div>
    <div class="col5">  <div class="d5" id="lang{$datum['id']}">{$datum['lang']}</div>

    </div>
    <div class="col6">
        <a href='images/{$datum['image']}' data-lightbox='picbox' data-title='{$datum['image']}'> <img src='images/{$datum['image']}'></a>
    </div>
</div>
ANY_IDENTIFIER_THAT_DOES_NOT_APPEAR_IN_THE_TEXT_HERE;
```

This last part must be exactly the same identifier as at the beginning, unindented and followed by a semicolon.

Also, note that I took out all of the `<?php` `?>` sections, and replaced them with `{$datum['image']}` accesses (unless I missed one). Heredocs in PHP work just like `"double quoted strings"`, except spread across multiple lines and able to include `"` marks.

For more information, see [the PHP documentation on string syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).